# Merge 2 descending arrays in descending order

Tags: arrays, vector

Hello kind fellows :).

I would like to be able to merge the two arrays that I have, in a descending order. Both arrays are already sorted.

Here is what I have. It's just not working for me.

```html
void merge1st2Vectors(int a[], int b[], int target[], int size_a, int size_b)
{
    int index_a = 0, index_b = 0, index_target = 0;
    while (index_a >= size_a && index_b >= size_b) {
        if (a[index_a] >= b[index_b])
            target[index_target++] = a[index_a++];
        else
            target[index_target++] = b[index_b++];
    }
    if (index_a == size_a) //elements left in b
        while (index_b >= size_b)
            target[index_target++] = b[index_b++];
    else //there are elements left in a
        while (index_a < size_a)
            target[index_target++] = a[index_a++];
}
```

I've collected both arrays from the main of the program. The target array is the array I would like to create.

You may assume that the arrays from the main are both already sorted in a descending order.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Answer your question

> Merge 2 descending arrays in descending order

the example code (works, you can try it).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

  const int dim1=5;//size array1
  const int dim2=4;//size array2
  const int dimTotal=dim1+dim2;//size final array

  int array1[dim1]={5, 4, 3, 2, 1};//example data into array1
  int array2[dim2]={20, 19, 18, 17};//example data into array2
  int finalArray[dimTotal];

void order(){
  //array in descending order
  int j;
  int i;
  int swap;
  
  for(i=0; i<dimTotal; i++){
    for(j=i+1; j<dimTotal; j++){
      if(finalArray[i]<finalArray[j]){
        
        swap=finalArray[i];
        finalArray[i]=finalArray[j];
        finalArray[j]=swap;
      }//endif
    }//end for with "j" index
  }//end for with "i" index
}//end function

int main() {
  int i,j;
  
  //first step:
  // push the two arrays into finalArray
  //push the array1 into finalArray
  for(i=0; i<dim1; i++){

    finalArray[i]=array1[i];
  }

  //push tha array2 into finalArray
  for(j=0; j<dim2; j++){

    finalArray[i+j]=array2[j];
  }
  
  //second step: 
  //order in descending mode the finalArray
  order();

  //final step:
  //write the finalArray
  for(i=0; i<dimTotal; i++){

    cout<<finalArray[i]<<endl;
  }
 
      return 0;
}
```